# How far is Rin from Deltora?

Tags: deltora-quest

*Deltora Quest* and its sequels and the Rowan of Rin series are both works by Emily Rodda (a.k.a Jennifer Rowe). 
Although it had been established previously that Deltora and the continent that Rin was on were in the same world, the *Star of Deltora* series situates them as within sailing distance of each other, since a Deltoran ship is able to draw near to the latter continent for trading purposes. Unfortunately, a map, let alone a scale map, doesn't seem to have been included.

How far is Rin and its continent from Deltora? Hundreds of miles? Thousands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approximately 1,000 nautical miles to the continent where Rin is located**

This is a guestimate based on the following information drawn from sources.

A study of [ancient sailing times in and around the Mediterranean Sea](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Journals/TAPA/82/Speed_under_Sail_of_Ancient_Ships*.html) comes to the conclusions that with a favourable wind, ships can achieve 4 - 6 knots (in open water) but only 2 - 2.5 knots with an unfavourable wind

The only site I've found so far that mentions the length of time that the *Star of Deltora* sailed for is the wiki page stating that the [voyage lasting almost 2 weeks](http://deltoraquest.wikia.com/wiki/Maris).

Taking the worst case scenario of the ship only facing unfavourable winds, from the study we can conclude that the maximum speed could of been around 2.5 knots.  This gives a maximum range of 840 Nautical Miles (20 knots for 14 days)

If the ship was blessed with favourable winds then we could assign a speed of between 4 and 6 knots as deduced by the same study.  If we take the average of 5 then the maximum range would be 1,680 Nautical Miles (120 knots for 14 days)

Using an average of 3.5 knots to allow for unfavourable winds during the voyage, we can estimate that the *Star of Deltora* would cover a distance of 1,176 nautical miles.  Other factors could also come into play of course, so this is an estimate only

Comment: Of course it could be that I've gone back to far in time for my sources and that the ship could reach higher speeds :)